# How to create an Href using a MySQL column VARCHAR/TEXT

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently trying to link a "courseName" variable from mySQL table into an a href ="" code because I don't want each clickable link to go to the same sight.

```
<a href = "#">'.$record['courseName'].'</a>
```

This is my current line of html code. I need to replace the # with .$record['courseURL'] but I can't find a way to do it. Is there anyone who can help or push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do this.

For example, let your $record['courseName'] variable be 'course.php'.

```
$record['courseName'] = 'main.php';
```

Your "a" tag should look something like this.

```
echo '<a href ='. $record['courseName'].'>'.$record['courseName'].'</a>';
```

Comment: You are an absolute life safer. I just had to replace courseName with courseURL inside the href because that was the part of the database I was trying to access. But regardless you are a lifesaver for that. You have no idea how many ways I tried that while failing over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the course url into href attribute. Try:

```php
  <a href="<?php echo $record['courseURL']; ?>">
     <?php echo $record['courseName']; ?>
  </a>
```